# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Entry'

Tags: python, tkinter

I get that `z` is an `Entry` and that 5 is an `integer` but I don't know how to change `z` to be an `integer` that the user could enter.
This is my code:

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

z = Entry(window, width=35, bg="white")
z.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=W)


def click():
    global YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS
    YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS=YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS.get()
    global YOUR_PASSWORD
    YOUR_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD.get()
    global TARGET_EMAIL
    TARGET_EMAIL=TARGET_EMAIL.get()
    global subject
    subject=subject.get()
    global msg
    msg=msg.get()
    global z
    z=z.get()

    send_email(subject, msg)

x = 5 + z
print(z)
```

Comment: are you aware that print will display it in terminal only?

Comment: Yea I am I was just testing stuff out

Comment: i added answer, hope it helped

Comment: This is the new error message I get                                                                                        Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'IntVar'

Comment: i hv updated the ans, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

In tkinter you have `StringVar()` and `IntVar()` for string and integer respectively. So here you need to use a keyword argument to Entry widget called `Entry(.....,textvariable=my_var)` and in tkinter you have to define the variable before using it, so here is your code and I have simplify your code if you have trouble understanding you can ask or just copy and use this.

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

my_var = IntVar()
z = Entry(window, width=35, bg="white",textvariable=my_var)
z.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=W)


def click():
    global YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS , YOUR_PASSWORD , TARGET_EMAIL , subject , msg

    YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS=YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS.get()

    YOUR_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD.get()

    TARGET_EMAIL=TARGET_EMAIL.get()

    subject=subject.get()

    msg=msg.get()

    send_email(subject, msg)

x = 5 + my_var.get()
print(my_var)
```

Note that i removed your assignment of `z = z.get()` as it might be wrong to say so, instead you can do this too.
also, to get the value of a entrybox you can use `z.get()` which means you last line of code will be

```
x = 5 + int(z.get())
print(z.get())
```

and I don't recommend using `z = z.get()` as you already have a z outside your function. Note that I'm using `int()` because in Python you cannot '+' a str and int.

Comment: This is the new error message I get                                                                                                  Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'IntVar'

Comment: Should be `x = 5 + my_var.get()`.

Comment: i am so sorry, for not getting dis right :(((( Thanks @acw1668